# Comparing client's XSRF-TOKEN to server's

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, http-headers, csrf

The requirement is that in each request XSRF-TOKEN value must be validated with one that is stored on server. 
Here is the security configuration:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http  
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                .usernameParameter(...)
                .passwordParameter(...)
                .loginPage("/").permitAll()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
                .and().logout().permitAll().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(...).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
```

.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

As I thought it would work, inside the `csrfHeaderFilter()` I can get a header from each request by using `request.getHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN")` and then just compare that token to one that is on the server which is acquired like so: `request.getSession(false).getAttribute("...CSRF_TOKEN").getToken()`

If they don't match - raise an error. But sometimes `request.getHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN")` returns null even after user has logged in. Why is this happening and how to know which requests need a check? And the most important is it OK to do a check like this?

Comment: Why are you doing that at all? The point of using the `CsrfFilter` is that it already does all of that.

Comment: @chrylis I've made some test requests, looks like system only tests that request header is equal to request cookie. It does not test whether XSRF-token in request is equal to one that is stored on server. You mean I should add some additional filter?

Comment: @chrylis Thanks to your comment I found a place where  CsrfFilter doFilterInternal() method was overriden. Looks like problem is there.